# Update individual cells in excel from values stored in variable

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I read values from table and store in variables.
i want to update value of each variable to a specific cell in an existing excel file

table contents

```
col1          col2        col3

1             3             5

2             4             6
```

Desired Excel output

```
A   B   C   D   E   F

1       3       5   

2       4       6
```

*A-F  represent Column in excel

i am able to do for cell A using Execute SQL Task, but struggling with 6 fields as multiple update statements are not possible in same execute sql task

Query used in execute sql task

```
update [Sheet1$A3:A3] SET F1=@var;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below approach worked for me

In excel, as the first row in the table would go to cells C2,G2 and K2
and the second row in the table would go to cells C3, G3 and K3

Using update query once for each row i am able to populate the values in the respective cells in excel.

```
update Sheet1$C2:K2 
update Sheet1$C3:K3
```

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it, but you could achieve it with a loop, you could assign a variable for the cells, which change each loop, First loop A second loop C and third E. The same you do with the value.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the loop working as you mentioned, will post an update if/ when i can get it to work.